# Laravel - how to make collection to show with foreach loop in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, push, laravel-blade

I have this code:

```
public function userbase($id)
{
    $articles = Auth::user()->articles()->get();
$offers = collect([]);
    foreach ($articles as $article) {
        $offers->merge(Offer::where('article_id',  $article['id'])->groupBy('user_id')->get());
    }
//return $offers;
    return view('articles.userbase', compact('article','offers'));
 }
```

at view blade I have:

```
 @foreach ($offers as $offer)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$offer->user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$offer->user->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$offer->user->phone}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-3 text-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Send message</a></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

but $offer give me this result `[]`,so I cant show this into blade...

Also I try:

```
$offers->push(Offer::where('article_id',  $article['id'])
       ->groupBy('user_id')
       ->get());
```

and then I get:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "user_id": 8,
            "article_id": 8,
            "price": 55,
            "comment": "",
            "created_at": "2016-04-12 16:24:21",
            "updated_at": "2016-04-12 16:24:21",
            "key": "",
            "title": "",
            "start": "Wed, 20 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000",
            "provera": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 180,
            "user_id": 11,
            "article_id": 8,
            "price": 55,
            "comment": "",
            "created_at": "2016-04-17 15:12:53",
            "updated_at": "2016-04-17 15:12:53",
            "key": "",
            "title": "",
            "start": "Wed, 01 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000",
            "provera": 41
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 132,
            "user_id": 8,
            "article_id": 13,
            "price": 11,
            "comment": "",
            "created_at": "2016-04-13 20:05:06",
            "updated_at": "2016-04-13 20:05:06",
            "key": "",
            "title": "",
            "start": "Tue, 19 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000",
            "provera": -1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 175,
            "user_id": 8,
            "article_id": 14,
            "price": 22,
            "comment": "",
            "created_at": "2016-04-16 10:06:51",
            "updated_at": "2016-04-16 10:06:51",
            "key": "",
            "title": "",
            "start": "Tue, 03 May 2016 00:00:00 +0000",
            "provera": 11
        }
    ],
    [],
    []
]
```

and again I cant show iy into blade template...
Also, I need to have unique user_id, so I need to get just first offer with uniqe id ...

How I can make it possbile?

Comment: What data are you initially trying to get? `Offer`s related to an `Article` that belong to a `User`?

Comment: You actually get offers for each article to group them by user_id (probably an article has one user). 
So it doesn't make sense.

Read about how sql joins work, to get related offers based on user id.